# How to implement SkeletonLoader / WirefreameLoader that is external to the wrapped component?

Tags: css, reactjs, skeleton-css-boilerplate, react-loading-skeleton

Imagine we have a UserCard component:

```
function UserCard(props) {
  const { avatarUrl, name, loading } = props
  return (
    <div className='UserCard'>
      <Avatar image={avatarUrl} />
      <Name name={name} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now we want to implement a wireframe loading for it.

- We can't design a wireframe copy of `Avatar` and `Name` components - their authors may and will change their size and shape, we don't want our skeleton to fall out of sync
- We can't insert our loader inside `Avatar` and `Name` components - we don't have control over them or their css
- We can control the space between `Avatar` and `Name` and wrap them from the outside
- `Avatar` and `Name` may have some transparent portions / border-radius and we want to draw our skeleton animation over their visible part

Ideally the usage of our `Loader` should look somewhat like this:

```
function UserCard(props) {
  const { avatarUrl, name, loading } = props
  return (
    <div className='UserCard'>
      <Loader loading={loading}>
        <Avatar image={avatarUrl} />
      </Loader>
      <Loader loading={loading}>
        <Name name={loading ? 'some text to control the size of the skeleton' : name} />
      </Loader>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What are the ways to achieve it?
What if we have similar restrictions but want to add skeleton loading to the `UserCard`. From outside we know it's a single div wrapping other divs and we want to show a skeleton instead of each of those child divs.

Comment: Just had an idea, setting css `> * {background: ...}` to show loader and `> * > * { visibility: hidden }` to hide children may work. Going to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the best I came up with is this:

```
// Usage:
// @use 'styles/loading';
// .loading {
//   @extend .wireframe;
// }
.wireframe {
  background-color: var(--colors-borderColor2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  color: transparent; // hide text
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;

  > * {
    visibility: hidden; // hide children
  }

  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      transparent,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4),
      transparent
    );
    animation: loading 1.5s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes loading {
    100% {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
  }
}
```

The components that should be wrapped are targeted by a css selector and skeleton shape and size can be adjusted below the `@extend`.

So our `UserCard` component would look like this:

```
import { stylesheet } from 'astroturf'

const styles = stylesheet`
  @use 'styles/loading';
  .UserCard {
    //...
  }
  
  .UserCard:global(.loading) {
    > * {
      @extend .wireframe;
      
     &:first-child {
       border-radius: 50%; // make avatar round
     }
    }
  }
`

function UserCard(props) {
  const { avatarUrl, name, loading } = props
  return (
    <div className={cx('UserCard', { loading })>
      <Avatar image={avatarUrl} />
      <Name name={name} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Not ideal but works for me.